# failed to open: /d/wlan_wcnss/power_stats Error = No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, android-studio

Trying to run my android app on my phone. Keep getting this error as soon as I try to open it, and immediately closes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible due to wrong **system time** setting on your device, try to correct it.